# BigQuery Equivalent of "CREATE TABLE my_table (LIKE your_table)"

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to create a table which schema is exactly the same as another table. In other SQL engines, I think I was able to use "CREATE TABLE my_table (*LIKE* your_table)" or some variations.

I couldn't find the equivalent in BigQuery yet. Is this possible in some fashion?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use this form:

```
CREATE TABLE dataset.new_table AS
SELECT *
FROM dataset.existing_table
LIMIT 0
```

This creates a new table with the same schema as the old one, and there is no cost due to the `LIMIT 0`.

Note that this does not preserve partitioning, table description, etc., however. Another option is to use the CLI (or API), making a copy of the table and then overwriting its contents, e.g.:

```
$ bq cp dataset.existing_table dataset.new_table
$ bq query --use_legacy_sql --replace --destination_table=dataset.new_table \
    "SELECT * FROM dataset.new_table LIMIT 0;"
```

Now the new table has the same structure and attributes as the original did.

Answer (score 1):

To create a partitioned and/or clustered table the syntax would be:

CREATE TABLE `project.dataset.clustered_table`
 PARTITION BY DATE(created_time)
 CLUSTER BY
   account_id
 AS SELECT * FROM `project.dataset.example_table` LIMIT 0